# Clarification on composite indexes with an ancestor and one property

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I need some clarification on whether or not I need a composite index on ancestor queries with one property.

1) Do I need a composite index when there is one property with ascending direction?

```
<datastore-index kind="Entity" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="Property" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

2) How about when the property is descending?

```
<datastore-index kind="Entity" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="Property" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

I ask because case (1) queries work without the composite index but case (2) queries do not from my tests. Not sure if something weird is going on. Could the direction of the property in the above examples be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the composite index is required in this case as the specification of the ancestor itself would virtually count as an additional property specification and the result couldn't be handled by the datastore's single-property default indexes as it would in these cases:

- ancestor query without a property specification
- non-ancestor query with a single property specification

My suspicion is, I believe, confirmed by the acceptance of this related answer: [Objectify DatastoreNeedIndexException error on Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965470/objectify-datastoreneedindexexception-error-on-order/41982453#41982453)

Answer (score 0):

Does your query use an inequality filter (greater than / less than... etc...)? Because you will need [a composite index for any "Queries with ancestor and inequality filters"](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#index_configuration)